# Rails: Dojo POST Request is being received as a GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, dojo

I'm trying to issue POST request on a simple button click through AJAX.

On the DOM, I have a button:

```
<button id="MyButton">Click Me!</button>
```

I have a snippet of javascript issue a post request:

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/request"],
    function(on, dom, request) { 
        on(dom.byId("MyButton"), "click", function(event) {
            request.post("/post_here").then(
                function(response) { alert(response); },
                function(error) { alert(error); }
            );
        });
    }
```

And I also have the following routes and controller action:

```
post 'post_here' => "controller#action"
```

And the controller action

```
def action
    Rails.logger.debug "Hello!"
    render nothing: true
end
```

When I click the button to issue the post request, I get an error message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/post_here"
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the Javascript. I can still submit a post request to that url with a form. I'm wondering if the HTTP Headers have anything to do with this.

Comment: I'm seeing that there is a cookie called "request_method=GET" in all of my traffic to and from the server. Is this the problem? If so, I can't seem to figure out how to remove that request_method=GET from my cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/request"],
function(on, dom, request) { 
    on(dom.byId("MyButton"), "click", function(event) {
        request("/post_here", {'method': 'POST' }).then(
            function(response) { alert(response); },
            function(error) { alert(error); }
        );
    });
}
```